# What's the best way to handle non-supported browsers in Dart?

Tags: javascript, dart

Dart is not supported on certain browsers, particularly so on certain mobile browsers like the stock Android browser. Rather than flake out, I'd like to show a "not supported" message.

So we've got some JS that throws up a DIV with a "not supported" message if it detects supposedly unsupported devices:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

// Android 1-4
if (/android [1-4]/i.test(ua)) {
  window.document.querySelector('#mobile-not-supported').style.display = '';
  window.document.querySelector('#application-root-container').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Trouble is this is showing for some devices where it actually does work. For example, on some Android devices it works on the Chrome browser, not the stock browser.

What's the best approach here? I'm not even sure of a strict list of supported browsers (there's just this: https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html#q-what-browsers-do-you-support-as-javascript-compilation-targets). Ideally, there's a way for JS to detect that some aspect of the app isn't working and only show the "not supported" message in those cases.

Comment: Instead of using the user agent string use the `supported` attribute. This attribute is on many `dart:html` objects.

Comment: Great, did not know about that. In the meantime, posting my own solution as a separate answer, which involves specifically looking for native Android browsers in the user agent string.

Comment: Sorry, but you'd seriously sacrifice everyone using the stock Android browser just to use Dart with its abundance of low adoption issues and immaturity (at this date)?.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum in short: yes, for now, as it's a modern app, we're small enough, and it's not a huge ask to switch to the Chrome app. Lots of modern web apps won't work on native Android. Later, though, I'd like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

My improved solution was to look for native Android specifically, in the user agent string.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

// Look for native Android browser, which Dart does not support.
var is_android = ((ua.indexOf('mozilla/5.0') > -1 && ua.indexOf('android ') > -1 &&    ua.indexOf('applewebkit') > -1) && !(ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1));
if (is_android) {
  window.document.querySelector('#mobile-not-supported').style.display = '';
  window.document.querySelector('#application-root-container').style.display = 'none';
}
```

In the future, I may try the `supported` property @caffinatedmonkey mentioned.